# VS Code shows multiple copies of the same file when browsing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I keep having this problem that VS Code is showing me multiple copies of the same file in my recently opened section. And I don't know how to get rid of this again

I've tried enabling `workbench.editor.revealIfOpen` to no effect.

Any inputs on how to only show one copy of the same file in recently opened?

[image: Screenshot of VS Code with multiple copies of the same file]

Comment: Might be related to an old [2018 issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61805#issuecomment-433594343). You may try clearing history and see if the problem persists

Comment: Thanks @EhabIbrahim I just did and for now the duplicate files are gone. Hopefully for good 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was because the extra copies where opened with a wrong path, it had `./` as a prefix. And vscode treats these as unique copies. It's been fixed for the ReScript extension in [this pull request](https://github.com/rescript-lang/rescript-vscode/pull/358).